# View is not getting round

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad

I need to design a view like card with rounded corner and shadow. I have one container view and inside that another view as like image I have attached. But when I am applying corner radius for the outer container view radius is getting set except the area which is having inner view. If I am making it clipToBounds = true then it is getting round all over but shadow is not coming. So plz help me out here.

Here is my code

```
    containerView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    containerView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    containerView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    containerView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1, height: 1)
    containerView.layer.shadowRadius = 5
    containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    containerView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
```

I am attaching Image below for for my issue. [View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vOKA.png)

Comment: Could you please share some code or even the repo where your code is?

Comment: I have added my code above..Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two views, a superview and its subview, and your goals are in conflict.

- On the one hand, you want the corner radius of the superview to affect its subview. That can happen only if the superview masks to its bounds.
- On the other hand, you want the superview's shadow to appear. That can happen only if the superview *doesn't* mask to its bounds.

So what you want is a logical impossibility.

The solution is easy. Use *three* views! Divide the job of shadow-making and clipping between two views.

- The outermost view has the corner radius and the shadow and doesn't mask to bounds. This is the shadow-maker.
- The next view is its subview. It is exactly the same size, and it *also* has the corner radius and it *does* mask to bounds. This is the clipper.
- The next view is the content, the subview(s) of the subview. It will be masked by the second view so the corner radius will affect it.